# Extracting Values From String

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have a string generated from `namelist()` of ZipFile and I want to save in a variable only the filename of the pdf file:

```
with ZipFile(zipfile, 'r') as f:
    filelist = f.namelist()
    print(filelist)
```

The output is: `['test.pdf', 'image_3.png', 'image-1.jpg', 'text-2.txt']`

For example I want to store in the variable `pdfname` the value `"test.pdf"`

Comment: Not sure if I got you right, but `filelist` is not a string, it's, well, a `list`, so you can get the first element and store it in a variable by indexing: `pdfname = filelist[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way:

```
with ZipFile(zipfile, 'r') as f:
   filelist = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".pdf"),f.namelist()))
   print(filelist)
```